# What currents are entering/exiting this end of the supernode?

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image: Unsure how to proceed with the supernode created by the 14V source]

I assigned the following currents. For one end of the 14V supernode, I have i1.
I'm not sure where the other end of the 14V supernode actually ends, so do I include only i3 in the KCL equation for it, or do I include i3 and i, or i3, i, and i2 (the rightmost current)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you should predefine the direction of all currents. If the final value of the current is negative, it means that you have to flip the originally defined current direction.

[image: circuit]

Considering KCL of each voltage loop

$$14V = i_1\cdot 4\Omega  + i_3\cdot 3\Omega $$

$$6V = i_2\cdot 1.5\Omega  - i_3\cdot 3\Omega $$

$$ i_1 = i_2 + i_3$$

Rearranging the equations you obtain:

$$i_1 = 3.6A$$

$$i_3 = -0.13A$$

$$i_1 = 3.73A$$

It means that at the node of interest, the current I_3 is flowing upwards and the current I2 coming from the parallel connection of the right most resistors are entering the node from the right side.

Comment: Sorry, how did you get $$i_1 = i_2 + i_3$$? Also I need to find the voltage and current labeled v and i (without subscripts) respectively, as shown in the original diagram.

Comment: Based on the currents you drawn, you just have to see what arrow / ucrrent points towards the node, and what arrow/current point outwards the node.

Comment: I uploaded an image to make it easier to understand. The current equation was obtained considering the A node currents.

Comment: You have already the I3 therefore it should be straight forward to find the voltage v (I x R). The same is applicable for the current I = i2a. You have already the current I2, you just have to the math and find how much of this current flows through the 2Ohm.

Comment: For the 6V equation, shouldn't it be 6i_2 instead of 1.5i_2? Also for the final answer you wrote two values for i1?

Comment: I already calculated considering the parallel connection of the 2Ohm and 6Ohm resistors (1.5 Ohm = 2*6 / (2 + 6))

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand it now - your diagram has helped a lot. I used current division to get the correct value for i2a and ohm's law to get the correct value for v.

Comment: glad to hear it helped you.